# How slow should a set grow in order to be countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory, cardinals

Let $R_n$ be the set of binary sequences of length $n$ and $A_n$ the subset of sequences having some property. The cardinality of $R_n$ is $2^n$ and the set of infinite binary sequences is uncountable

What should be the cardinality of $A_n$ to ensure that the subset of infinite binary sequences having such property is countable/uncountable?

Comment: Is the limit of the $R_n$ their union, or do you mean something else?

Comment: How do you figure that if $|R_n|=3^n$ then $R$ is uncountable? Consider for instance $R_n=\{ 1,2,\dots,3^n \}$; presumably the set-theoretic limit of that is just $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo no, not necessarily

Comment: Anyway, if limits are just unions: $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}R_n$ is uncountable if and only if at least one of the $R_n$ is uncountable. In particular, a countable union of finite sets is always countable.

Comment: Which measure do you use for $|~\cdot~|$. If it is the Lebesgue measure, then $A_n$ is uncountable if $|A_n|>0$ and therefore $A$ is also uncountable. If $|~\cdot~|$ is the number of elements and $R_n$ should be uncountable, then $|R_n|=\infty$.

Comment: Ok, so what precisely do you mean by limit? What are these sets? (Arbitrary sets? Sets of reals?) What precisely does $|A_n|$ mean? (Cardinality? Measure?) Does the notation mean that $n$ ranges over $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @Ian I thought about it like the set of infinite sequences with terms in $\{0,1,2\}$

Comment: @Pedro That's not usually referred to as a set-theoretic limit. Usually we define $A=\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$ by $x \in A$ if and only if $x \in A_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. Similarly cardinality is not nicely continuous: even though $3^{\aleph_0}=\beth_1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \{ 1,2,\dots,n \}=\aleph_0$, it is not true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} 3^n = \beth_1$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo i mean cardinality

Comment: @Ian sorry. If you understand what i mean please help me make it clearer

Comment: Pedro, it seems that you have a specific *different* question in mind, and you're trying to ask something else. Where did this problem come up, and what are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes it came from a similar question (i'll edit the quesiton) but I was trying to generalize

Comment: @Ian: Actually, this works better if you don't use sets inside your limit, but their cardinality. Clearly, the sequence $3^n$ is a subsequence of the sequence $n$; so if the limit of $n$ is $\aleph_0$, the limit of $3^n$ cannot be different. So what we have here is a discontinuity. (Which, of course, is not a very surprising thing when you think about it... why should cardinality be continuous?)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair point; I just didn't want to try to define the limit of a sequence of cardinals, but you're right that it's better to do so here (and it's not really that hard, anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edit, it sounds like you're asking the following. For each $n$, we have some set $A_n$ of binary strings of length $n$; and you're asking about the set $\mathcal{A}$ of infinite binary strings, whose length-$n$ initial segments lie in $A_n$ for all $n$. For instance, if $A_n$ is the set of length-$n$ binary sequences with no "$11$"s, then "$00000000000...$" would be in $\mathcal{A}$. And so on.

If this is correct, then there is a description of when $\mathcal{A}$ is countable - but it's not as simple as a constraint on the growth of the $A_n$s; it has to do with how they interact with each other. **And this leads to a complicated answer, which is more technical than you might be expecting. What I've written is really only a sketch - let me know if there are parts you don't understand, and I'll try to fill them in better.**

First, let's make the picture a bit more understandable. $\mathcal{A}$ is really the set of *paths through a certain binary tree* $T$, whose length-$n$ nodes are exactly the strings in $A_n$. (I'm assuming here that the $A_n$s are nested appropriately - if $\sigma\in A_{n+1}$, the length-$n$ initial segment of $\sigma$ is in $A_n$. You only get into $A_{n+1}$ by going through $A_n$.) For simplicity, let's assume that we can always extend an element of $A_n$ to an element of $A_{n+1}$ - that is, there are no "dead ends" in the tree $T$.

One nice feature of this tree picture is that we can just describe the tree, and not have to describe each $A_n$ separately. E.g. if we take $A_n$ to be the set of binary sequences of length $n$ with no "$11$"s, we can more quickly describe this picture as "The tree of binary sequences with no "$11$"s." I'll do so below.

Now we can "prune" such a tree, as follows. Say a path $f$ is *isolated* if there is some finite sequence $\sigma$ such that $f$ is the only path going through $\sigma$; intuitively, this means that for some $n$, there's some $\sigma\in A_n$ such that

- $\sigma$ has only one extension in $A_{n+1}$
- and only one extension in $A_{n+2}$
- and so on,

that is, *from the perspective of $\sigma$* the $A_n$s stop growing at all.

**Exercise: regardless of what $T$ is, there can be only countably many isolated paths.** This is because we can associate each isolated path to a finite binary sequence which isolates it ...

OK, so this gives us our first result:

> If every element of $\mathcal{A}$ is isolated, then $\mathcal{A}$ is countable.

But that's not the only way that $\mathcal{A}$ could be countable! For example, let $T$ be the tree of finite binary sequences not containing "$10$." There are only countably many of these - they're either the zero-sequence or a sequence of the form $000...000111111111...$. But if you draw the tree $T$, you'll see that *the element $0000000...$ is not isolated*! It's the "limit" of other elements: namely, in an appropriate sense $0111..., 00111..., 000111..., ...$ approaches the zero-sequence.

How will we account for this? Simple - **we keep pruning**! The all-zeroes path becomes isolated *once we remove the isolated paths*. And we can keep going: we remove the paths that become isolated once we remove the isolated paths, and then we remove the paths that become isolated once we remove *those* paths, and so on.

At this point, it might be good to see another example:

> Consider the tree $T$ of finite binary sequences such that: if they have at least two "$1$," then there is no $0$ following the second $1$. That is, they look like a string of zeroes, then a one, then a string of zeroes, and then unending ones. By "string" here I mean possible-empty, possibly-infinite; so e.g. the all-zeroes sequence is a path through $T$, as is the all-$1$s sequence. This tree looks a lot like infinitely many copies of the tree from the previous example, "glued together" along a path.

**It's a very good exercise to try to draw this tree.** In this tree, we have lots of isolated paths, lots of limits-of-isolated-paths paths, and one limit-of-limits-of-isolated-paths path. So the tree "vanishes" after we prune **three times**.

We can go into the transfinite, too: after all the finite steps, we take "what's left" - that's a new tree! And then we can prune *its* isolated paths, and so on.

This is the [**Cantor-Bendixson process**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)). It can be hard to visualize at first, but it's quite useful. And a very nice theorem states that this process characterizes when $\mathcal{A}$ is uncountable:

- If $\mathcal{A}$ is countable, then at some (countable) stage the entire tree disappears.
- If $\mathcal{A}$ is uncountable, then our tree never disappears; in fact, at some (countable) stage, we're left with a *perfect tree* - a (nonempty) tree with no isolated paths at all! *(This tree is called the *perfect kernel* of the original tree, and the set of paths through it is called the *perfect kernel* of $\mathcal{A}$.)* An example of a perfect tree is the full binary tree, $2^{<\omega}$.

So whether $\mathcal{A}$ is countable or not is characterized exactly by the Cantor-Bendixson process. Unfortunately, this is rather complicated, and definitely not what you were hoping for - but there it is.

Comment: Incidentally, every perfect tree has continuum-many paths; this means that whenever I have a set of paths through a binary tree, it's either countable or has size continuum, *regardless of whether the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) holds*. The set of paths through a given tree is a closed set, but we can prove this for Borel sets as well. This is the beginning of [descriptive set theory](https://tinyurl.com/y865txvg); the idea is that these sets are "too nice" to have weird properties - like being counterexamples to CH, or being nonmeasurable, or ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I needed. I got a bit confused but now I think i understand it

Comment: @Pedro Glad I could help! There's a lot to digest here - this was historically the beginning of a whole subfield of mathematical logic, and has a lot of technical nuance - so definitely let me know if there's a point you'd like me to explain better, I'll be happy to do so!

Comment: I'll try to apply all of this to the proof I have in mind. If I get stuck how can i make you know? (if you want of course)

Comment: Just add a comment here, I'll be automatically notified. (I can't guarantee that I'll have time to help, but I think there's a decent chance I will.) And of course, if *I* can't help, you could ask it as a question here ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Very nice and instructive answer. (+1)